# Bomb lab phase_4

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-64

```
Dump of assembler code for function func4
    <+0>: mov %rbx,-0x18(%rsp)
    <+5>: mov %rbp, -0x10(%rsp)
    <+10>: mov %r12,-0x8(%rsp)
    <+15>: sub $0x18,%rsp
    <+19>: mov %edi,%ebx
    <+21>: mov %esi,%ebp
    <+23>: test %edi, %edi
    <+25>: jg 0x400fb2<func4+34>
    <+27>: mov $0x0,%ebp
    <+32>: jmp 0x400fd2<func4+66>
    <+34> cmp $0x1, %edi
    <+37>: je 0x400fd2<func4+66>
    <+39>: lea -0x1(%rbx),%edi
    <+42>: callq 0x400f90 <func4>
    <+47>: mov %eax,%r12d
    <+50>: lea -0x2(%rbx),%edi
    <+53>: mov %ebp,%esi
    <+55>: callq 0x400f90 <func4>
    <+60>: lea (%r12,%rax,1),%eax
    <+64>: add %eax,ebp
    <+66>: mov %ebp, %eax
    <+68>: mov (%rsp),%rbx
    <+72>: mov 0x8(%rsp), %rbp
    <+77>: mov 0x10(%rsp),%r12
    <+82>: add $0x18,%rsp
    <+86>: retq
```

This is the disassembled code of func4.
And I'm not sure whether I understood this function correctly or not.

I didn't write the disassembled code of phase_4 here,
but it needs "%d %d" input, and first integer should be in range 1<=x<4.
So it should be 1,2,or 3.
And register %edi has the value 7 at first.
After the call of func4, code compare the value of 0x10(%rsp) and %eax
So I should know the %eax value after the call of func4.

I thought, disassembled code of func4 means

```
put the stack
ebx = edi
ebp = esi
if edi is not zero
    if edi is one: then eax=ebp.
                   rearrange the stack
                   return.
    else: edi = -0x1(rbx)
          func4
          r12d = eax
          edi = -0x2(rbx)
          esi = ebp
          func4
          eax = rax+r12+ebp
          rearrange the stack and return.
else
    ebp=0
    eax=ebp
    return
```

But with my understanding, I can't solve it.
For example, if the original address of %rsp was 0x7fffffffd5a8
then the address would be smaller until the value of edi becomes 0.
I found that the value of 0x7fffffffd56f is 0 - and the first func4 call ends- 
but after that value of 0x7fffffffd56e is also 0 - so the second func4 call ends - 
and all of registers become 0, including eax.

So I thought the answer of second number is zero,
but (1,0), (2,0), (3,0) always explodes bomb.

Cound you guess where I am wrong and help?

Comment: Please double-check your disassembly, it has some nonsensical parts indicating copy-paste error. Such as `ebp` missing `%`, or `$px18` instead of presumably `$0x18`. It's hard to figure out if you don't provide the actual code correctly.

Comment: @Jester I saw your comment, and you're right. There were several mistakes in my disassembled code and I changed them correctly. Thanks to inform me about this.

Comment: Okay so now you should update your pseudocode accordingly ;)

Comment: I checked my pseudocode too, but there was nothing wrong. (I changed some words because of readability, but anyway..) If the pseudocode is wrong, then maybe I misunderstood something

Comment: It's missing for example line `+21` which does `ebp=esi`. Side note: it helps to know that `edi` and `esi` are the first two arguments passed to the function.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I added more lines in pseudocode. But still I can't guess what value %eax should be..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edi` and `esi` are the two arguments to `func4`. This is according to standard calling convention, but can also be deduced from the fact that these registers are used without initialization, so their value must come from outside. As such, the prototype is `int func4(int a, int b)`.

Line `+23` check to see if `a > 0`, and jumps away if it is. So we can easily trace what happens if the condition is false:

```c
if (a <= 0) return 0;
```

Line `+34` is checking if `a == 1`, and if so, the current value of `ebp` is returned, but that has been initialized from `esi` which is the second argument, `b`:

```c
if (a == 1) return b;
```

Otherwise, lines `+39`..`+55` recursively invoke `func4`. Line `+60` adds the result of the two invocations together, and line `+64` adds `b`. So we have:

```c
return func4(a - 1, b) + func4(a - 2, b) + b;
```

From this you can calculate the returned value for any input.

Of course if you are allowed to use a debugger, you can just let the code run and see what the value of `eax` is going to be ;)

Comment: In disassembled code of phase_4, esi is set to 0x14(%rsp), which is the second input of phase_4, and edi is set to 7. According to your explanation, func4(edi,esi) returns func4(edi-1,esi)+func4(edi-2,esi)+esi. So func4(7,esi) returns 33*esi. 

And the phase_4 compares 0x10(%rsp) and eax. So first input of phase_4 should be 33*(second input of phase_4). Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Oh, I solved phase_4! Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate all the help you've given me :)